# JTable cómo cambiar la visualización de una celda en particular

Tags: java, java-swing

Lo del título, deseo crear una edición individual de las celdas, no quiero usar DefaultTableRenderer, porque para eso necesito saber de ante mano qué celdas voy a editar y  hacer un condicional ejemplo

```
if(row == 0 && column ==1) {
 // El usuario está en el componente (0,1);
   this.setBackground(new java.awt.Color.GRAY);
)}
```

el problema es qué no sé que celdas voy a editar, ya que deseo que el usuario mismo decida a cuál ponerle color, a cuál no, la idea es hacer un método que me obtenga el componente Swing de la celda dentro de la tabla, NO EL VALOR, si no el componente, para poder editarlo, he googleado lo más que he podido, pero generalmente el código sirve cuando uno sabe de ante mano qué celdas va a cambiar ):

Ayuda.

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package prueba;

/**
 * 
 * @author Eduen Sarceno 
 */
public class tablaPersonalizada extends javax.swing.JTable {

    public void setColorCelda(int fila, int columna, java.awt.Color color){
        /* Codigo que lo haría */
    }


    public void setTLetraCelda(int fila, int columna, int tamano){
        /* codigo que lo haría */
    }



}
```

Comment: Un listener no sería la solución?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo mas común es sobre-escribir el método [`prepareRenderer()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#prepareRenderer(javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer,%20int,%20int))

```
JTable table = new JTable(datos, nombresColumnas) {
    @Override
    public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int col) {
        Component comp = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, col);
       // Object value = getModel().getValueAt(row, col);
        if (getSelectedRow() == row && getSelectedCol() == col) { //Al seleccionar columna y fila.
               comp.setBackground(Color.red); //Cambia color!
               comp.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 40)); //Cambia estilo y tamano de fuente.
        } else {
            comp.setBackground(Color.white); //Color default (blanco).
        }
        return comp;
    }
};
```

- información método [`setBackground()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setBackground(java.awt.Color)) (inglés).
- información método [`setFont()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setFont(java.awt.Font)) (inglés)

Comment: algún documento que me puedas brindar ya sea en inglés donde expliquen la personalización total del JTable, por ahora tengo una clase que quisiera hacer su respectiva visualización, pero me quedo corto,gracias por la respuesta .

Answer (score 0):

Encontre un modo simple es solo para cambiar el color y otros atributos con HTML

```
model.addRow( new Object[]{
              "COLUMN 1",
              "<html><font color=\"blue\">TEXTO AZUL</font></html>"
});
tabla.setModel(model);
```

Espero te sirva.